Openhift Error en el POD al intentar obtener la imagen Failed to pull image "image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/..." OpenShift CRC
Al reiniciar uno de los Pods se me presenta el siguiente mensaje:
Failed to pull image "image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/openshift/image-base:3.1.0.dev.1-centos7": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = reading manifest 3.1.0.dev.1-centos7 in image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/openshift/image-base: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

OpenShift V14.10.38

pueden ser varios los motivos (no existe la imagen o problemas de autenticación con el registry), seria de gran ayuda que nos compartas el manifiesto .yaml, donde estas definiendo el pod.

Muchas gracias Xllauca. Al parecer es un tema del certificado que venció porque nos quedamos en la versión 14.10 y deberíamos haber migrado a la ultima; no hemos podido realizar dicha migración. Como se soluciona lo de los certificados de las imagenes mientras tanto? ya reviso como compartir el .yaml del pod
